# Do anti-particle black hole exist and can they evaporate?

Tags: black-hole, hawking-radiation

I know that virtual particles are constantly be created and annihilated even in a complete vacuum, I like to know if there exist such a mechanism to spawn an anti-particle black hole can be any size not necessary stellar? I think black hole lose mass by gradually throwing out one of the pair of virtual particles before they could cancel out each other, so would this also apply to an anti-particle black hole as well if it does exists?

Comment: The notion of matter - anti-matter doesn't exist for anything beyond the event horizon of a black hole. If the question is whether black holes can be created using anti-matter alone, then the answer is most certainly yes. All you need is enough energy / gravity to collapse the given amount anti-matter to a size smaller than the Schwarzschild Radius for its mass. Evaporation of a black hole via [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) is a thermodynamic process and therefore doesn't particularly depend on the nature of the matter outside the event horizon.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Perhaps make that comment an answer.

Comment: Why does the concept of M/AM not exist inside a black hole? It might not be observable from outside the EH and so unverifiable to such an observer, but AIUI it is not impossible that we are all inside an event horizon (though it's quite possible this idea is now out of date given advances in cosmological theory).